compiled with problems plugin react was conflicted
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\TERMINUX\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\TERMINUX\Frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
what is this error about
always getting this error  whenever I refresh the page
